# Android setChecked animation

Tags: android, checkbox, android-viewpager

I have a problem on checkbox animation when `setChecked(true)`.
Let me explain my condition.

I have a `gridview` inside `viewpager` and one checkbox above the `viewpager`.
I set an adapter to `gridview`. There are a checkbox and a icon in the adapter.

When click an item, checkbox animation works fine. However, when try to select all items by one checkbox above the `viewpager`, all items are selected without checkbox animation, just can see only 2 views, checked box and unchecked box.

Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
// ViewHolder
CheckBox mCb;
mCb.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        mCb.setChecked(Model.isChecked());
    }
});
```

Um... The problem with this code is a bit slow

Comment: at first look it's not seems to handle this problem. but it did